No consigo que se muestren unas coordenadas en leaflet con proj4.js
Estoy diseñando un mapa web usando leaflet. Uno de los eventos que quiero añadir es el de pasar con el ratón sobre el mapa y que te vaya mostrando abajo a un lado, las coordenadas por las que pasa el ratón. Me salen en geográficas con este código:
 // Div para mostrar las coordenadas
    var coordsDiv = document.getElementById('coordinates');

 // Evento de movimiento del ratón
    map.on('mousemove', function(e) {
    coordsDiv.innerHTML = `Latitud: ${e.latlng.lat.toFixed(5)}, Longitud: 
    ${e.latlng.lng.toFixed(5)}`;
    });

Pero me gustaría que además se vean en otros sistemas también, por ejemplo, que aparezcan en X e y, en ETRS89, etc. He probado con este otro código, para el que hay que usar proj4.js, puede que no lo esté integrando bien?:
    // Se definen las proyecciones
    proj4.defs("EPSG:4326", "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs");
    proj4.defs("EPSG:4258", "+proj=longlat +datum=ETRS89 +no_defs");

    // Evento de movimiento del ratón
    map.on('mousemove', function(e) {
        var coordsWGS84 = [e.latlng.lng, e.latlng.lat];
        var coordsETRS89 = proj4("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:4258", coordsWGS84);

    coordsDiv.innerHTML = `
    WGS84 - Latitud: ${e.latlng.lat.toFixed(5)}, Longitud: ${e.latlng.lng.toFixed(5)}<br>
    ETRS89 - Latitud: ${coordsETRS89[1].toFixed(5)}, Longitud: ${coordsETRS89[0].toFixed(5)}
        `;
    });

Este es el script de proj4.js que uso:
No entiendo por qué sigue sin salirme.
Gracias!!

Por si no conseguís respuesta acá, te recomiendo que acudas a [gis.se] (en inglés) para ver si alguien obtuvo un problema similar. De no ser así, también podrías preguntar allá. La etiqueta parece ser [proj4js].

Muchas gracias padaleiana!! probaré suerte, un saludo!
